# CSS/JS Overlay Zoom Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got problems regarding my image gallery site that uses PhotoZoom Javascript (Zooms image during mouseover). Hope you guys can help me out.

Problem:
The photozoom javascript works perfectly during mouseover event. However the zoomed image is under the other images. I've tried manipulating the Z-INDEX in the CSS but nothing worked. What could be the possible solution to see the zoomed image above everything else?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some `css` which helped me,

```
<style type="text/css">
.photoZoom-Large{
  z-index:100 !important;
}
</style>
```

Try adding this code in your documents `<head>` section.

and here is `output` of same:

[image: Output]

Hope it helps! cheers :).

Comment: Should be `z-index:100 !important;` :)

Comment: Thanks @misterManSam, But it can even work without `!important`.

Comment: @emotheraphy, I'm glad that I could help you.

Comment: Thanks also to you @misterManSam more power to both of you. :)